# How to store database session in Tornado RequestHandler

Tags: python, session, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, tornado

I'm implementing a secure cookie scheme for user session management in Tornado. The user's details are accessed via SQLAlchemy. Currently I need to open two database sessions: one to verify that a user exists during authentication, and another to query other parts of the model. Something like this:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        user_id = self.get_secure_cookie('user')
        if not user_id:
            return None
        with model.session_scope() as session:
            user = session.query(model.AppUser).get(user_id)
            if not user:
                return None
            session.expunge(user)
        return user

class OtherHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @gen.coroutine
    def put(self, ob_id):
        with model.session_scope() as session:
             other = session.query(model.Other).get(ob_id)
             session.merge(self.current_user)
             if not user.can_view(other):
                 raise AuthzError
             yield self.some_operation(other)
        self.finish()
```

It would be nice if I didn't have to use `merge` to bring the user object back into the session. Is there a safe way to store the database session and [persistent](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#quickie-intro-to-object-states) `user` object in the handler? I'm considering doing something like this:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        self.session = model.Session()
        user_id = self.get_secure_cookie('user')
        if user_id:
            self.current_user = session.query(model.AppUser).get(user_id)

    def finish(self, chunk=None):
        try:
            return super().finish(chunk)
        finally:
            self.session.commit()

    def send_error(self, status_code=500, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().send_error(status_code=status_code, **kwargs)
        finally:
            self.session.rollback()
```

Questions:

1. Is it **safe** to store the `session` (or anything else) in `self`, even when using async code (`@gen.coroutine` and `yield`)?
2. Is the way I'm closing the session in `finish` and `send_error` **robust**? I want to make sure I don't have any zombie sessions hanging around.

Comment: No related to your question but, I thing querying db using SQLAlchemy from Tornado would block the server.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the way I'm closing the session in finish and send_error robust? I want to make sure I don't have any zombie sessions hanging around

You can use either [`on_finish`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_finish) or [`on_connection_close`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_connection_close).

```
def on_finish(self):
    if self.get_status_code() >= 500:
        self.session.rollback()
    else:
        self.session.commit()
```

Note that may exist a better way to distinguish an error response. Also take a look at the discussion - https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/517

> Is it safe to store the session (or anything else) in self, even when using async code (@gen.coroutine and yield)?

The `RequestHandler` object is created for every request, it's not shared. Asynchronous in that context, does not make the code more vulnerable (I think) to store data in "`self`".

Comment: I'm not sure `on_finish` is robust enough. It's [called by `finish`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.finish), which doesn't do any exception handling to ensure that `on_finish` really gets called. Thanks for the tip about `on_connection_close`. Assuming I stick with `finish` or `on_finish`, I should probably override that too.  It would be nice if Tornado had a clearly-defined method for cleaning up resources :/